# Responsive email Outlook 2003 - 2013 issues

Tags: html, email, responsive-design, outlook, html-table

So I have a responsive email that has a left and right box. Which looks like this:

[image: Successful email render]

But in Microsoft Outlook 2003 - 2013 these two blocks render like this:

[image: Unsuccessful email render]

---

You can find my code for these boxes here: https://jsfiddle.net/uhjjqkmo/

Unfortunately I am unable to post the full code (discretion of the client).

Example DOM layout:

```
<!-- START:LEFT -->
<table width="295" align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Left
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<!-- END:LEFT -->

<!-- START:RIGHT -->
<table width="295" align="right" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Right
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<!-- END:RIGHT -->
```

Comment: Welcome to the exciting world of email rendering!! You'll need to enclose your tables inside a container table.

Comment: @PA. Please see https://jsfiddle.net/uhjjqkmo/ for actual working code that is inside a container table. Thanks.

Comment: sorry, I mislead you, you will need to enclose each table inside a cell of the container table, and give the size to that cell, instead.

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/uhjjqkmo/5/

Comment: @PA. Yes you are correct but with this being a responsive email both left and right boxes become full width on smaller devices. Putting each box into their own cell prevents us to make them full width on smaller devices. Yes we can add 100% width on each cell but this is ignored on major mobile clients.

Answer (score 0):

I have added some extra css rules to your code:

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uhjjqkmo/8/)

- And I found out that it was better to put width="49%" on the floating tables (instead of width="295")

BEFORE:
[image]

AFTER:
[image]

Then an extra tip I can give you is to combine align and float.

```
<table align="right" style="float:right; Float: right;">
    <tr>
        <td width="200"><img src="" alt="" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This to get the best possible results for floating tables in email e.g. when trying to float an image in text ;)